# Join two tables and get the last record

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
select names.name,test,from_id,test,text from names join test on names.id=test.from_id where test.to=1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Agreed with Joachim.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to get the last record, and if you use MySQL database, you can use `LIMIT` combined with `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT names.name,test.from_id,test.text
 FROM names JOIN test ON names.id=test.from_id
 WHERE test.to=1
 ORDER BY names.id
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: are you sure about last?

Comment: Yes, at least if you fix the selected column names in your query, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f90a1e/1

Comment: from result table their two rows but buy using that answer it appear only one row

Comment: I thought from your question, you wanted only the last record...?

Comment: no i wanted all record but only last for duplicated record

Comment: still am comfused about result help me please to get the answer because am suffer for a long time and i believe that your my survivor

Comment: i want the last record for duplicated record only otherwise other record appear

Comment: How do you distinguish between duplicated records? If they are the same, `SELECT DISTINCT ...` may be your solution.